# app is crashing due to tiny_malloc_from_free_list

Tags: iphone, crash

Am working on an iPhone app,everything was going fine until I faced this crash, tiny_malloc_from_free_list. I am not sure why this crash is happening all of a sudden.Tried to google it but seems there aint enough suggestions to fix this one.
Please suggest any ideas how I can fix this problem.

Thanks,
Manoj

for reference here are some methods:

```
-(void) fetchProfileData
{

    // Implemented ASIHTTP Request APIs 
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString:SERVICE_NAME_PROFILEMANAGER] autorelease];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    [request setUsername:[[LoginManager sharedInstance] userName]];
    [request setPassword:[[LoginManager sharedInstance] passWord]];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:autheticateIndicator];
    [autheticateIndicator startAnimating];
    [authenticationLabel setHidden:NO];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];              
    NSString *theXml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(parseXML:) toTarget:self withObject:theXml];
    [autheticateIndicator stopAnimating];
    [theXml release];
}

-(void) parseXML:(NSString *)xmlData
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [profilePersonnelNumber removeAllObjects];

    //  Load and parse the string data
    tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLString:xmlData] retain];

    //  If TBXML found a root node, process element and iterate all children
    if (tbxml.rootXMLElement) {
        [self traverseElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
    }

    if ([profilePersonnelNumber count] > 0 ) {

        NSDictionary *dict = [profilePersonnelNumber objectAtIndex:0];

        if ([dict objectForKey:@"PersonnelNumber"])
            {
                [array release];
                array = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[dict valueForKey:@"PersonnelNumber"], nil] retain];

                NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                for (NSObject * obj in array)
                {
                    [result appendString:[obj description]];
                    [[LoginManager sharedInstance] personnelNumber:[obj description]];
                }                   
                [result release];
            }
    }

    [tbxml release];
    [pool release];

    //TODO: Uncomment this part, must required

    if ([profilePersonnelNumber count] > 0) {
        UITabBarController *controller = self.tabBarController;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: where does the debugger crash at in your code? we need more info than this, a stack trace might also be helpful

Comment: Please paste all your code or you might get negative votes for your questions.

Comment: I have a loginview controller, after validating my user credential am showing a tabarbar controller with tableviews. It was working perfectly fine for some days now and no where this crash showed up all of a sudden. Could you please tell me how this crash is associated with the code/controller?

Comment: okay here I pasted 3 of my methods, I know its bit tough to readable. But I can explain here better, -(void) fetchprofiledata will initiate an ASIhhtprquest ansynchronous call and if the response is positive requestfinished delegate method is getting called where am spawning a new thread with selector method parseXML and passing the xml as object. In parseXML method after parsing the xml, if am getting an array of elements like personnel number etc.. am showing the tabbar controller.

Comment: Can you please format your code properly. It's very difficult to read.

Comment: Stephen I have pasted the code now,right below my query.
Can you see it now ?

Comment: The crash might be due to removing the delegate of asihttprequest from memory? Are you removing loginViewController when you display TabBar?

Comment: Okay I think I got the problem, when I am spawning a child thread, till it executes the actions its blocking my main thread to update the UI. Any comments on this ??